# Replication not updating XML Schema collection

Tags: sql-server, replication

So the problem I'm facing is that replication from our Main instance to our Data Warehouse instance is failing because it isn't picking up XML schema updates. Thus, when it tries to bulk copy the data from the Main table that utilizes it, it fails because XML validation fails due to the XMLSchemaCollection not containing any of the updates.

The behavior that we've observed in the last couple months is that if the XML schema is new, then replication picks it up. However, from that point forward, it ignores it. This smells like a deficiency in the way it detects updates. But I'm hoping that someone else has figure this out.

Comment: What type of replication are you using?

Comment: I believe it is snapshot, but I'm trying to verify that.

Comment: I looked at the publication for the main database and it appears to be transactional

Comment: Okay, what does sp_helparticle return for the article which contains this column?  Specifically, I'm wanting to know what gets returned for schema_option.

Comment: It just says "Command(s) completed successfully." I'm not sure I'm doing it right. Bear with me, I'm kinda new at replication.

Comment: `USE MyPublicationDB; EXEC sp_helparticle @publication = 'MyPublicationName', @article = 'MyArticleName';

Comment: schema_option = 0x0000000048035EDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Publish Data and Database Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559.aspx) in the section *Considerations for Publishing - Limitations on Publishing Objects*:

> XML schema collections can be replicated but changes are not
>   replicated after the initial snapshot.

I agree, this appears to be a deficiency.

As a workaround, you could perform the XML schema update on the Publisher and then post the XML schema update to Subscribers using [sp_addscriptexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174360.aspx).

Comment: So when I apply an xml schema to a table, it force validates all data in that table. Wouldn't this workaround cause this to happen on both the the publisher and all subscribers?